# Inserting a big text file into netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans, netbeans-6.9

```
try {
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("Help.txt"));
            String helptext = br.readLine();

            helpText.setText(helptext);

        } catch (IOException e) {
              System.out.println ("Error: " + e);
        }
```

It only returns the first line of the text file and the text file is about 4 pages long. 
"helptext" being a text area.I want the whole file with its spaces I made in the text area.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to loop through the text file. You are only telling it to readline() one time.

**EDIT: Fixed code to be exactly what user needed**

**EDIT 2: Added code to keep cursor at top**

```
String line; 


try {            
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("<Location of text file>"));

     while((line=br.readLine()) != null){               
     helpText.append(line);
     //Add a new line for the next entry (If you would like)
     helpText.append("\n");
    } 
      //Set Cursor back to start
      helpText.setCaretPosition(WIDTH);
    }
   catch (IOException e) {             
   System.out.println (e);         
 }
```

Comment: what the helptext contain it and if you set helpText.setText(helpText) like this the only last line will be display

Comment: @Waldo King Copy and paste any of the given answers code. If this doesn't work your file is to big it seems to be read in this way.

Comment: @Waldo King You may also want to look into threading, if your file is so big that you lose control of your program. I jsut tested with a huge text file I locked up but it went through. Good Luck

Comment: Ok thank you that helped alot. One last thing. when the help file open's now it starts at th bottom and you must scroll all the way up. Is it easy for it 2 say start at top?

Comment: @Waldo King, I added it to my answer

Comment: @Waldo King No problemo. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

This will give only 1 line where in your file the first line whatever contain to get all the line you need get into the loop

```
StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();

String line = null;
while((line=br.readLine()) !=null){
     sb.append(line);
}

helpText.setText(sb.toString());
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to read every line in a loop.

```
String line = br.readLine();

String helptext = "";

while(line != null) {
     helptext = helptext + line;
     line =  br.readLine();
}

 helpText.setText(helptext);
```